# Javascript Raphael SVG Map loads very slow in IE 7/8

Tags: javascript, html, raphael

Im having a problem with Raphael and a custom map svg plugin Im using. I am pretty sure the problem is related to Raphael and redrawing vectors every time the map reloads. The map works perfectly in Firefox/Chrome/IE9. In IE 7/8 the map runs incredibly slow and its almost non usable. The icons also turn white sometimes. It seems the positioning happens before the re-sizing of the elements happens in IE8 and that's where the bottleneck seems to occur. Here is a link to the map:

http://www.comparewebads.com/VisaInteractiveMAP/world.html

The file that handles the map functionality is mapsvg.js.
http://www.comparewebads.com/VisaInteractiveMAP/js/mapsvg.js

Answer (score 0):

I know this isn't a comprehensive answer, but some of my own research in a related area tells me that browsers' javascript performance, especially in terms of graphics performance in svg, canvas, etc, has improved exponentially over their past few versions. IE is especially notorious for poor performance (in any version).

I suspect that at least a part of your problem is simply that IE 7 and 8 have comparatively slow and inefficient javascript engines.

In my own javascript-heavy projects I refuse to support anything before IE9, because IE 7 and IE8 simply can't handle the performance (and some features just aren't included.)

Comment: I would have simply added this to your original post in a comment instead of answering, but my reputation isn't high enough yet to let me comment on others' posts.

Comment: The map has to work in IE8. Any ideas about the Javascript code itself? Any ways I resize the objects with faster updates.